# URL in an SMS message is being invoked

Tags: php, url, text, sms

I am developing a system that can run marketing campaigns over SMS.  These text messages have an link in the text message.  the idea is that the user can click on the link in the text message and the offer will be issued to them.  I am able to send the text message and the link looks good in it. However, without my even opening the text message, the link is being invoked.  This is causing the offer to be issued to the user, even before he clicks on it.

I am shortening the URL for the offer using google's url api but I get the same behavior even if I do not shorten the URL.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing the link to be invoked.  It almost as if it is being tested.

Any help would be helpful.

Waqar

Comment: Show your text-message code.

Comment: I am using Twilio to send text message.  Here is the php code that sends the text message.   

try{
   $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $this->authToken);
   $client->account->messages->sendMessage($subNumber, $to, $message, null);
   return true;
  } catch (\Exception $ex){
   $error = $ex->getMessage();
   \Log::error ( $ex );
   return false;
  }

the actual message with the URL is in the message variable.